# pass parameter from javascript to another jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to pass parameter from a Javascript function to another JSP page. Currently I am doing like this:

```
function viewapplet(strPerfMonPoint) {
    var dateSelected = document.forms[0].hdnDateSelected.value;
    document.forms[0].hdnPerfMonPoint.value = strPerfMonPoint;
    var win;   
    win = window.open("jsp/PopUp.jsp?GraphPerfMon="+strPerfMonPoint+"&strDateSelected="+dateSelected, strPerfMonPoint,"width=800,height=625,top=40,left=60 resizable=No");     
}
```

I added `hdnPerfMonPoint` hidden variable and tried to acces in `PopUp.jsp` using `request.getparameter(hdnPerfMonPoint)` but it is giving null.

I want my window.open like:

```
window.open("jsp/PopUp.jsp", strPerfMonPoint,"width=800,height=625,top=40,left=60 resizable=No");
```

Please suggest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Are you quoting it properly? (and note the name change!)

```
String GraphPerfMon = request.getParameter("GraphPerfMon");
```

"The returned value of a parameter is a string. If the requested parameter does not exist, then a ***null*** value is returned."

Comment: Thanks for ur quick response ...
Actually i want this parameter in my scriplets... not in javascript... yeah i am getting GraphPerfMon and strDateSelected using request.getparameter() method..
I want that my url doesnot show values of GraphPerfMon and strDateSelected

Comment: if you need it in the JSP, and can't pass it on the URL you have only a few options. e.g. you could set something in the session via AJAX... and retrieve it in the popup... or you could submit a form via post on your opener... with a target attribute set top your new window name (but you lose the ability to resize the popup/control any chrome features)

Answer (score 1):

You've actually passed it as `GraphPerfMon` as well. So `request.getParameter("GraphPerfMon")` should return the desired value. If you really insist in using the value of the hidden input element of the opener window instead for some reason, then you need Javascript.

```
var hdnPerfMonPoint = window.opener.document.forms[0].hdnPerfMonPoint.value;
```

To learn more about the wall between JSP and Javascript, you may find [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html) useful as well.